# Scrapy Logging: Format statscollectors timestamps differently

Tags: python, scrapy

When a standard scrapy spider finishes its crawl, it will log a summary of the scrape using the statscollectors module that looks something like this (truncated):

```
2021-03-21 15:11:16 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/exception_count': 4,
 'elapsed_time_seconds': 91125.763498,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2021, 3, 21, 14, 11, 6, 806324),
 'item_scraped_count': 30395,
 'log_count/ERROR': 4,
 'log_count/INFO': 574,
 'log_count/WARNING': 38,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2021, 3, 20, 12, 52, 21, 42826)}
```

I would like to format the `start_time` and `end_time` values differently, to make it easier to process my log files as part of a monitoring pipeline. Eg,

`datetime.datetime(2021, 3, 21, 14, 11, 6, 806324)` => `2021-03-21 14:11:06.806324`.

I don't see anyway to change this in [logging settings](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/logging.html#topics-logging-settings). Any idea how I can effect the formatting for the statscollectors module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't super obvious, but you can define a [`closed`](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#scrapy.spiders.Spider.closed) function on your spider that will execute when the spider is closed and you can access the `stats` through the `crawler`. You could use it to log the start/end times like so

```py
def closed(self, reason):
    self.logger.info("Start time: %s", self.crawler.stats.get_value("start_time"))
    self.logger.info("End time: %s", self.crawler.stats.get_value("start_time"))
```

If you want to turn off the stats dump at the end then this can be done using the [`STATS_DUMP`](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#stats-dump) setting